# My GoogleApiClient always connected false

Tags: google-signin

Why GoogleApiClient always connected false. I use next code for google auth.

```
private var gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestServerAuthCode(CLIENT_ID)
    .requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.LEGACY_USERINFO_PROFILE))
    .requestIdToken(CLIENT_ID)
    .requestEmail()
    .build()

private var mApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(fragment.requireContext())
    .enableAutoManage(fragment.requireActivity()) { }
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build()

init {
    mApiClient.connect()
}

fun onGoogleAuth(key: Int) {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mApiClient)
    val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mApiClient)
    fragment.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, key)
}

fun handleGoogleAuthResult(data: Intent): String? {
    val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
    if (result!!.isSuccess) {
        val acct = result.signInAccount
        return acct!!.serverAuthCode
    }
    throw NullPointerException()
}

fun onCancel() {
    mApiClient.stopAutoManage(fragment.requireActivity())
    mApiClient.disconnect()
}
```

I want take signOut, but because mApiClient always connected false, this not work.

here is an example of how I used signOut

```
fun onGoogleAuth(key: Int) {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mApiClient)
    val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mApiClient)
    fragment.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, key)
}
```